# Get class objects of multiple objects

Tags: r

For my function to perform well I need to get the class object of multiple objects that meet the following condition:

1. The first class sends `TRUE` when the object is all three: `list, character, character`.
2. The second class should send `TRUE` when the object is all three: `list, character, numeric`.

For example:

```
first_class <- list('prediction','median')
second_class <- list('prediction', c(1, 2, 3, 4))

test_class_object <- function(class_object) {
  if (is(class_object, 'list') == TRUE &
      is(class_object[[1]], 'character') == TRUE &
      is(class_object[[2]], 'character') == TRUE) {
    print('all characters')
  } else if (is(class_object, 'list') == TRUE &
             is(class_object[[1]], 'character') == TRUE &
             is(class_object[[2]], 'numeric') == TRUE) {
    print('last is numeric')
  }
}
```

Whilst this works ok for small number of objects, if I had a larger list of objects like 15 then this would be very messy. How can I in the most simplest form repeat this function?

Updated with @Akruns answer:

```
test_class_object <- function(class_object) {
    if(is(class_object,'list') == TRUE){
      if ({
        c(class(class_object), sapply(class_object, function(x)class(x)[1]))%>% last() == 'character'
      } ){print('all characters')} else if(
        {
          c(class(class_object), sapply(class_object, function(x)class(x)[1]))%>% last() == 'numeric'
        } 
      ){print('last is numeric')} else print('not found')
    }else {
      stop("You need a list object, for example: list('prediction','median)")
    }
```

This allows for more mobility, I'll also have to check into @r2Evans comment because as it stands my lists have single class objects, but I may get multiples in the near future.

Comment: You can use `sapply` i.e. `c(class(first_class), sapply(first_class, class))`

Comment: @akrun brilliant! I had this option instead: ```append(list('list'), map(first_class, class))```

Comment: One thing to be careful of, though ... while `class(1)` and `class("A")` are both length 1, `class(Sys.time())`, `class(tibble(mtcars))`, `class(as.data.table(mtcars))` are all length 2 or more (e.g., with grouping). If you want to use `class`, safeguard against this by either (1) sapply(class_object, function(z) class(z)[1])` or (2) wrapping the `list` of returned classes with `sapply(.., `[`, 1)`.

Comment: @r2evans you are so right! I can't believe I missed this - I'll look into your suggestion. So far, I am only testing if the last class from the list is either `numeric` or `characters`. I aim to vary this whereby some multiple of them meets the condition i.e. all even values in the list are `characters`.

Comment: (those code blocks should have read `sapply(class_object, function(z) class(z)[1])` and `sapply(.., \`[\`, 1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to get the `class` of inner list elements, use `lapply/sapply` to get the class i.e.

```
c(class(first_class), sapply(first_class, class))
```

returns a `vector`

```
c(class(first_class), lapply(first_class, class))
```

returns a `list`, then can use a vector of class values to compare

Comment: @teslajohn thanks, I didn't add that in the function as I was not sure about your custom messages

Comment: That is fine, it gives me the opportunity to look into things further - I have noticed a minor mistake in my update. Turns out I could also do `test_class_object('hi')` and it would return a character. So I made the additional update with a `stop` to introduce an error otherwise. Thank you for your help.